# xml input validation in restful webservice

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have a requirement that I need to send an xml file to the rest resource. And there I need to do some validation on that xml file. If the validation succeed then only that obj will be added. Can anyone give input on how to proceed.

Comment: You need to provide more information on what framework you're using or how your application looks like.

Comment: i am using Spring framework. My application should consist of a resource and a post request to send xml to the resource and there to do validation I need to convert that into an obj. If succeed add that obj to collection.

Comment: what framework are you using for REST implementation at server side. BTW for validation you can use XSD validation. XSD = XML Schemas. Google it

Comment: I can use XSD. But here my requirement is that I need to convert the incoming xml to java obj and then do validations like some element should contain only number...etc. If the xml meets the requirements then add obj to collection. For this what is the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a validation in way you would validate an input of a method and throw a [`WebApplicationException`](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html) if something is not right:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
public void upload(@FormParam("xml") String xml) {
  try {
    Document doc = this.parse(xml);
  } catch (SAXException ex) {
    throw new WebApplicationException(
      ex,
      Response.status(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST).build()
    );
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you can accept XML as an HTTP POST body:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
public void upload(String xml) {
  // the same as above
}
```

Otherwise, you can use JAXB to convert your incoming XML into JAXB-annotated class ([read more](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkknj.html)):

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes("application/xml")
public void upload(Product product) {
  assert product.price().equals("50 USD");
}
```

Comment: whats that parse() actually do? should I override that method in my class? and i dont want to use @formparam. I am sending the xml through restclient for firefox addon.

Comment: `parse()` is your custom method, which should parse the XML to get a `Document`. You should implement it.

Comment: I dont want to convert xml to Document. I have a pojo class which represents the xml. I want to convert the xml to that class obj. How to do that.